# More efficiently perform join and update

Tags: mysql

I'm doing some work on a database to make it more organized.  Currently each record is identified by the combination of 3 columns - so it currently has a unique key that is made up of three items, `u1`, `u2`, and `u3`.  However, I have another table that links `u1`, `u2`, and `u3`, to another unique id, `uid`.  The table with the triple unique identifier has monthly values, whereas the one with the single id is simply an informational column.  I want to take the `uid` from the informational table and put it in the monthly table.  So I created a `uid` column in the monthly table and wrote this query.

Explain output is below:

```
UPDATE monthly_table
INNER JOIN information_table ON
monthly_table.u1 = information_table.u1 AND monthly_table.u2 = information_table.u2
AND monthly_table.u3 = information_table.u3
SET monthly_table.uid = information_table.uid;
```

Unfortunately I have around 8 million rows in the monthly table, and when I run this query (from the command line) it takes around 1 hour to complete.  I have set the InnoDB cache to 3 or 4GB.  I have also put indexes on keys `u1`,`u2`, and `u3` in both tables, and `EXPLAIN` says there will be 2 simple selects using those keys.

Is there any way to make this query more efficient so that it more quickly?  I'm not doing this often, but I would like to know in case I need to do it again, and for the sake of better understanding of mySQL.

```
+------+-------------+-----------------------+------+---------------------------+----------+---------+-----------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table                 | type | possible_keys             | key      | key_len | ref                                           | rows    | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-----------------------+------+---------------------------+----------+---------+-----------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | monthly_table         | ALL  | u1,u2,u3                  | NULL     | NULL    | NULL                                          | 8284393 | Using where |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | information_table     | ref  | u2,u1,u3                  | u3       | 33      |dbname.monthly_table.u1                        |       2 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-----------------------+------+---------------------------+----------+---------+-----------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+
```

Comment: Can you include the EXPLAIN output.

Comment: @dan08 - added explain output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three indexes for each table, for the columns u1, u2 and u3 respectively. This isn't going to help much, since any given query can only use one index at a time.

Instead you need, for each table, an index that spans all the columns that compose the primary or unique key:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX monthly_table_my_index
ON monthly_table (u1, u2, u3);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX information_table_my_index
ON information_table (u1, u2, u3);
```

Comment: Took me a bit to get ready for another test... Thanks!  I also used FORCE INDEX  to make sure it used that index.